# Select ActiveCell in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a project that will sort all the cells in another worksheet based on criteria. I need to activate a cell in another worksheet to make it work. I tried finding a solution but no luck. 
I recorded a macro from my workbook and tweaked it a bit so it would fit my need. When I run the code, Runtime Error 1004 appears. 
I need a code to replace

```
SetRange ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Range("A1:AF30436")
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
Sheets("Source").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Source").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Source").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=ActiveCell.Range _
    ("A1:A30435"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Source").Sort
    .SetRange ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Range("A1:AF30436")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Comment: Your question is not clear: you want to activate Cell cA in Sheet sA and get Sheet sB to be sorted according to the value in cA? Maybe you should try finding a solution in 2 steps. First, try sorting by passing a value into a function. Next, bind that solution into an Event on a Worksheet.

Comment: I want to activate cA so I can select all cells (excluding header) and sort it alphabetically. The workbook has 30,000+ rows that needed sorting. I tried looping but it's too slow.The code above is in another sheet(MAIN). When I press the button on sB(MAIN), the sA(Source)sheet should select all sheets in that same sheet and be sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you record macro, you click on the cell in the second sheet and start the sort routine. Macro correctly recorded this.

however when you are doing this in VBA, the "active cell" could be anything and in most cases you dont need this as long as you know the datarange that you need to work with

```
dim ws as WorkSheet
set ws = Sheets("Source")
ws.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ws.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Range _
        ("A1:A30435"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
With ws.Sort
  .SetRange Range("A1:AF30436") ' Change here to itended dataset
  .Header = xlYes
  .MatchCase = False
  .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
  .SortMethod = xlPinYin
  .Apply
End With
```

Comment: The code deleted all data in Column F and several other columns. Thank you for explaining the difference between recording macro and in vba

Comment: did you change the range before executing?

Comment: No. I intended to sort only from cell A2 to cell AF30436, because it has a header. I am not sure why the macro recorder got A1 instead of A2

Comment: doesnt matter, the sort table includes the header. .Header = xlYes 
so the recorder got A1 corectly

Comment: please try again ( I have replaced Active Cell in one another place)

Comment: It worked! Thank you! :D I also have another question regarding autofilter and activecells in macro, should I post the code here or make a new post?

Comment: please make another post so you get a better chance. particularly this question will look like it has answers and may not receive the attention you need

Comment: Hello, @Krishna. This is the question I posted regarding active cells and autofilter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264942/autofilter-in-another-sheet-macro-recorded Thank you! :)