# Autofilter in another sheet using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I intend to filter values that begins with 314 in column F, and clear its contents(entire row). The workbook has 30,000+ rows and I think looping is not a good option when filtering in another sheet(sA). I recorded the following code below.

```
Sheets("sA").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AF$30436").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="=314*" _
    , Operator:=xlAnd
ActiveCell.Offset(-181, -2).Range("A1:AF30436").Select
ActiveCell.Activate
Selection.ClearContents
```

When I ran the code, a Runtime Error 1004 appears. I think because of the ActiveCell, because I ran the code in a different sheet(sB, where the button for filtering sheets in sA is found). What could be the possible fix to this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work ,

```
Sub filter()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Set ws = Sheets("sheet1")

   ws.Range("$A$1:$AF$30436").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="=314*" _
    , Operator:=xlAnd

   Dim LR As Long
   LR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   ws.Range("A2:AF" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).ClearContents
   ws.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: It only filtered values starting with 314. Should I add ws.ClearContents at the bottom?

Comment: so you are expecting to see more records? your criteria says records in field 6 starting with 314... sorry if i missed the point

Comment: sorry i get the question - do you want to clear the rows or delete them?

Comment: I intend to filter only the rows in which values starting with 314 in column F. After the values starting at 314 in column F is filtered, all of its rows should be deleted entirely.

Comment: Right now I just want to clear the rows. My original goal was to filter them, delete entire rows and also delete the blanks that was left from it. But I could just clear the rows and make use of the code that you gave me in the other post.

Comment: please see my edit. this should delete and you dont need to worry about the residue blank rows

Comment: The sheet has 25,000+ rows after filtering, I tried the code. It's still running.

Comment: shouldnt take long, there may be a prompt on the excel window asking for confirmation to delete rows. can you check please

Comment: Yes, a dialog box appeared. As of now it's still running. Maybe because the rows are so many. 25,000+ rows to delete. Maybe a clear option instead?

Comment: please try now, I replaced with ClearContents. Press Ctrl+Break to exit from the current running process

Comment: I tried the code, it worked! Thank you! :D Is there an option to turn autofilter off after clearing the contents?

Comment: please see edit, but now you will be getting blank rows. Use the prevously provided Delete method at some stage to clean up the sheet

Comment: I apologize if I replied too late. I just tried the code. Flawless. I'm in awe. Thank you so much! You're a lifesaver.:D