# Wildcards in Excel Cross-Sheet Autofilters

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I am trying to create an autofilter with VBA (Excel 2013). I have found two difficulties:

- First, the cross-sheet filtering is not working
- Second, I cannot add the * wildcard automatically, even after trying many suggestions found here and elsewhere on the internet. I am also having trouble with multiple field filtering, but that could be solved via using 2 filters.

My code:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Szuro")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Geodeta_adatok")

ws2.Range("A1").Autofilter _
  Field:=1, _
  Criteria:=ws.Range("C1").Value
```

I would like the search string to behave as follows: The value in `C1` plus `*` wildcards before and after the string.

[I tried the solution from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264942/autofilter-in-another-sheet-using-vba), but it is not working. When I run my code (even without any wildcard solution) I keep getting the following error: "Compile error: Named argument not found" with the criteria highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter is `Criteria1`, not `Criteria` but that may have been a simple typo.

I typically use `Chr(42)` to produce an asterisk but `"*"` should work as well. Concatenating them into the criteria string should give you the *Contains* filter you are looking for.

```
ws2.Range("A1").AutoFilter _
    Field:=1, _
    Criteria1:=Chr(42) & ws.Range("C1").Text & Chr(42)
```

The [AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844%28v=office.11%29.aspx) uses a predominantly text based pattern match when dealing with wildcards.

If I understand the term *'cross-sheet filtering'* correctly, you should be looking at the [Advanced Filter method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221800(v=office.11).aspx) rather than AutoFilter.